# how to structure beginning and ending synchronous calls using trio?

Tags: python-trio

My ask is for structured trio pseudo-code (actual trio function-calls, but dummy worker-does-work-here fill-in) so I can understand and try out good flow-control practices for switching between synchronous and asynchronous processes.

I want to do the following...

- load a file of json-data into a data-dict

  - aside: the data-dict looks like { 'key_a': {(info_dict_a)}, 'key_b': {info_dict_b} }
- have each of n-workers...

  - access that data-dict to find the next record-to-process info-dict
  - prepare some data from the record-being-processed and post the data to a url
  - process the post-response to update a 'response' key in the record-being-processed info-dict
  - update the data-dict with the key's info-dict
  - overwrite the original file of json-data with the updated data-dict

Aside: I know there are other ways I could achieve my overall goal than the clunky repeated rewrite of a json file -- but I'm not asking for that input; I really would like to understand trio well enough to be able to use it for *this* flow.

So, the processes that I want to be synchronous:

- the get next record-to-process info-dict
- the updating of the data-dict
- the overwriting of the original file of json-data with the updated data-dict

New to trio, I have working code [here](https://github.com/Brown-University-Library/annex_receipts/blob/0fe4c0186b5f92b2edc12b9f153fa05ed536bf6c/past_files_poster.py#L215-L221) ...which I believe *is* getting the next record-to-process synchronously (via using a trio.Semaphore() technique). But I'm pretty sure I'm *not* saving the file synchronously.

Learning Go a few years ago, I felt I grokked the approaches to interweaving synchronous and asynchronous calls -- but am not there yet with trio. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses channels to multiplex requests to and from a pool of workers.  I found the [additional requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250706/combining-semaphore-and-time-limiting-in-python-trio-with-asks-http-request) (in your code comments) that the post-response rate is throttled, so `read_entries` sleeps after each `send`.

```
from random import random    
import time, asks, trio    

snd_input, rcv_input = trio.open_memory_channel(0)
snd_output, rcv_output = trio.open_memory_channel(0)    

async def read_entries():
    async with snd_input:
        for key_entry in range(10):
            print("reading", key_entry)    
            await snd_input.send(key_entry)    
            await trio.sleep(1)    

async def work(n):
    async for key_entry in rcv_input:    
        print(f"w{n} {time.monotonic()} posting", key_entry)    
        r = await asks.post(f"https://httpbin.org/delay/{5 * random()}")
        await snd_output.send((r.status_code, key_entry))

async def save_entries():    
    async for entry in rcv_output:    
        print("saving", entry)    

async def main():    
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
        nursery.start_soon(read_entries)    
        nursery.start_soon(save_entries)    
        async with snd_output:
            async with trio.open_nursery() as workers:
                for n in range(3):
                    workers.start_soon(work, n)

trio.run(main)
```

Comment: Thanks for the runnable pseudo-code! Wasn't asking for it to actually work -- but that allowed me to add lots of print-statements and experimentation-tweaks to learn quickly. Giving you the checkmark because I really wanted to know how I could save the updated full-data-dict synchronously -- as it was updated -- if I wanted to.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would write the (pseudo-)code:

```py
    async def process_file(input_file):
        # load the file synchronously
        with open(input_file) as fd:
            data = json.load(fd)

        # iterate over your dict asynchronously
        async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
            for key, sub in data.items():
                if sub['updated'] is None:
                    sub['updated'] = 'in_progress'
                    nursery.start_soon(post_update, {key: sub})

        # save your result json synchronously
        save_file(data, input_file)
```

`trio` guarantees you that once you exit the `async with` block every *task* you spawned is complete so you can safely save your file because no more update will occur.

I also removed the `grab_next_entry` function because it seems to me that this function will iterate over the same keys (incrementally) at each call (giving a O(n!)) complexity while you could simplify it by just iterating over your dict once (dropping the complexity to O(n))

You don't need the `Semaphore` either, except if you want to limit the number of parallel `post_update` calls. But `trio` offers a builtin mechanism for this as well thanks to its [CapacityLimiter](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-core.html#trio.CapacityLimiter) that you would use like this:

```py
    limit = trio.CapacityLimiter(10)
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
        async with limit:
            for x in z:
                nursery.start_soon(func, x)
```

**UPDATE thanks to [@njsmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1925449/nathaniel-j-smith)'s comment**

So, in order to limit the amount of concurrent `post_update` you'll rewrite it like this:

```py
    async def post_update(data, limit):
        async with limit:
            ...
```

And then you can rewrite the previous loop like that:

```py
    limit = trio.CapacityLimiter(10)
    # iterate over your dict asynchronously
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
        for key, sub in data.items():
            if sub['updated'] is None:
                sub['updated'] = 'in_progress'
                nursery.start_soon(post_update, {key: sub}, limit)
```

This way, we spawn *n* tasks for the *n* entries in your data-dict, but if there are more than 10 tasks running concurrently, then the extra ones will have to wait for the limit to be released (at the end of the `async with limit` block).

Comment: Unfortunately that `CapacityLimiter` example at the end won't work :-/. Each time you use `async with limit` it claims one of the 10 slots until you exit the block. It doesn't automatically integrate with nurseries or task spawning. So your example is saying, at most 10 tasks at a time can be *doing the loop to start more tasks*... but there's no limit on how many tasks they can spawn.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info and pseudo code. I _had_ wanted to see an example for how I could save the data-dict file synchronously -- after each micro-update, which [my interpretation](https://github.com/birkin/trio_exp_code/blob/master/concurrency_flow_02.py) of your code does not do. But thanks also for the CapacityLimiter example usage. Cool to see the queue build up and be processed via print-statements.